# Show autocomplete suggestions on another event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, autocomplete, show

I have two inputs - `#postal` and `#name`. `#name` input has a jQuery autocomplete function enabled. Suggestions for autocomplete are shown only when I start typing something into `#name` input.

I need to show suggestions of `#name` input even if I type something into `#postal` input too. I was trying:

```
$('#postal').keyup( function () {
    var postal = $('#postal').val();
    $('#name').autocomplete( "option", "source", getFilteredSuggestionsJson(suggestionsJson, postal));
    $('#name').autocomplete("search");
});
```

I also tried: `$('#name').trigger('keydown.autocomplete');` but none of that worked for me. Keyup event is triggering correctly, but can't get that suggestions visible. What could I do?

---

I just found out it works only when I first bring autosuggestions by typing something into #name input and hide it when focus from `#name` is lost. Only after that I can show autosuggestions by typing into `#postal` input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

This is what you're looking for `myAutocomplete.autocomplete("search", $(this).val());`

```
var myAutocomplete = $('input#name').autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 1
});
$('input#postal').keyup(function(){
    console.log('keypress');
    myAutocomplete.autocomplete("search", $(this).val());
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W56yq/95/)

Comment: Well thanks, now it works. Btw. better is to use keyup() method, otherwise last letter stay ignored.